# Building custom keras loss function with use of gradients of output with respect to output

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to build a neural network to evaluate option prices. It is well known that putting no arbitrage constraints inside the loss function of neural network will enhance its out-of-sample performance. To do so, I need to implement the custom loss function described at page 7 of this paper :

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03507.pdf

However, I am unable to consitently do so. From what I have understood so far, this would require to customize the train step.

Does anyone has a code example of something similar or could explain me how I should proceed ?